# Is there anyway I can bring up the "chrome://settings/" for the user?

Tags: google-chrome, settings

As the question is saying, I'm curious to know, is there anyway that the settings of the chrome browser can be popped up for the user? with html or javascript? or any other language?

Comment: You *may* be able to include such a link, but from within chrome it likely requires explicit user-interaction (i.e. "click"). If just launching chrome (i.e. from external process) then it's passing the URL as a startup argument.

Comment: @user2246674 can you give me an example how can I start it up?

Comment: From where? You can't start up / launch an arbitrary process from (browser) "html/javascript".

Comment: Anywhere, I'm just curious. So there is no way to do machine-interaction instead of the user-interaction?

Comment: There is no "anywhere" in this context. Are you displaying from a C# Application? A Chrome extension? Some random Webpage? Each context is a specific *somewhere* :)

Comment: Lets say I'm showing from a random WebPage

Comment: Then "You *may* be able to include such a link, but from *within* chrome it likely requires explicit user-interaction (i.e. "click")." You'll have to try it out, of course as it may be entirely blocked.